# CONNECT SQLITE DATABASE TO ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, sqlite

How can I connect my SQLITE database in ECLIPSE? My sqlite is 2.o version, while the eclipse has 3.5.9 version of sqlite. Is there something to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

1) Write your database code

2) Google "jdbc driver sqlite"

3) Download whatever JDBC driver for Sqlite (presumably SqlLite3) you like best, and add the .jar to your project

4) Modify your code to open the desired driver with the (driver-specific) JDBC connection string

5) Voila.  Done :)